# iOS layout pattern

Tags: ios, xcode, layout

I'm developing an iOS application, and I would like to use a similar layout used in iOS settings, but I'm not sure if there is any predefined components to use, or if there's some predefined layout which does exactly what I want to achieve. It looks like this:

[image: iOS 7 settings menu]
<sub>(source: [iphonehacks.com](http://cdn.iphonehacks.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/ios-7-settings-2.png))</sub>

I'm looking for the 'Behavior' header, the white elements like 'Animate Icon'. Do I have to create them from scratch using labels, textfields and so on, or are there any predefined components available?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears to be a `UITableView` using the *grouped* style, and the string 'Behavior' was returned from the `tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:` datasource method, which is defined in the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol.

You can select the *grouped* style in storyboard by selecting the table view and changing the `style` with the *Attributes inspector*.